# java.lang.runtimeexception unable to start activity componentinfo

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

i am having this error in this code

> java.lang.runtimeexception unable to start activity componentinfo

```
package estimatewall.example.com.estimatewall;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText inputTxt;
    EditText inputTxt1;
    TextView setText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        inputTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        // Store EditText in Variable

        int val = Integer.parseInt(inputTxt.getText().toString());

        inputTxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        // Store EditText in Variable

        int val1 = Integer.parseInt(inputTxt1.getText().toString());

        float block1,block2;
        final float sum;
        block1=(val*12)/7;
        block2=(val1*12)/10;
        sum=block1*block2;

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Perform action on click
                try {
                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                    textView.setText("" + sum);
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });





    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat and .xml also

Comment: In other words complete error stack so we can see what and where was thrown

Comment: Have you define style for support library??? If you haven't defined then define it in style `"Theme.AppCompat.Light"`

Answer (score 1):

Probably getting `NumberFormatException` because here:

```
int val = Integer.parseInt(inputTxt.getText().toString());
```

trying to convert `null` to `int`.

Use `inputTxt.getText()` inside `onClick` method of Button on click listener to get values input by user in Edittext or set some default values in xml for both EditText's as `android:text="0"`